# Serve a specific url using express

Tags: node.js, http, express

Having an `express` application and two routes, how can I serve route `/foo` when accessing route `/bar`?

```
app.get("/foo", (req, res) => res.end("Hello World"));
app.get("/bar", (req, res) => /* ??? */);
```

I don't want to redirect using `res.redirect("/foo")` because that will change the url. From what I saw [`connect-middleware`](https://github.com/tinganho/connect-modrewrite) would do this job, but it's too complex for what I need.

I only need to forward the request to the `/foo` route instead and serve it to the client under the `/bar` route.

How can I do that such as when I open `/bar` in the browser, I will get back `"Hello World"`?

I also don't want a regex solution. I want a function like this: `res.serveUrl("/foo")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write also your own "rewriting" engine. In this example you just rewrite the URL and use `next()` to reach the desired handler:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
    req.url = '/bar';
    return next();
});

app.get('/bar', function (req, res) {
    console.dir(req.url);           // /bar
    console.dir(req.originalUrl);   // /foo
    console.dir(req.path);          // /bar
    console.dir(req.route.path);    // /bar
    res.send('Hello bar!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

You can still access the original url using `req.originalUrl`

Others ([express-urlrewrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-urlrewrite)) already thought of such middleware as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create handler function and use it in both routes

```
function handleFooAndBar (req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
}

app.get("/foo", handleFooAndBar); 
app.get("/bar", handleFooAndBar);
```

Comment: Well, this is yet another solution, but I really want to *serve another route* when a route is requested.

Comment: What do you mean by *serve another route*? my solution will serve "Hello World!" for /bar as well as /foo. Isn't this what you want.

Comment: I know this will work, but what I need is to forward the request to another route and send the response to the requested route, without having a function reference that serves the response. I need something like `serveReponse(req, res, "/my-url-to-be-served")`.

Comment: The URL is available in handleFooAndBar with *req.url* so it is exactly the same as your serveResponse

Comment: Yes, but suppose in another file I have `app.get("/bar", ...)` and here I want to serve a random route, without having the reference to that function.

Comment: Wait in your question you are saying you want the same hello world to be served for /bar. I'm sorry I am lost. I just don't understand what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106536/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-molda).