# Routes priority in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I want to implement the following routes' priority in `express` (in this order): custom urls, static files, error pages.

Current I did it like this:

```
let router = express.Router();

// custom urls (defined by me)
router.get("/foo", ...);

app.use(router);

// static files
app.use("/", express.static("path/to/public"));

// error pages (404, 500):
router.use((req, res, next) => { res.send("Custom 404 page."); });
router.use((err, req, res, next) => { res.send("Custom 500 page."); });
```

The problem I have is I'm getting `Custom 404 page` for static files. If I remove the error page routes, the static files work fine, but I don't get custom 404 error pages and 500 error pages.

How can I handle the `400` and `500` custom error pages while keeping this priority too?

Comment: I think it's `res.send` .

Comment: @JasterTDCClan Yes, probably typo. :) Not sure, but maybe `end` works too.

Comment: I have this in my code for static files `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`.

Comment: When you in your `javascript` code , request something like this `require('/js/jquery.min.js')` express looks inside your static directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your static files are in the `public` folder relative to your `index.js`, this works as expected:

Folder structure:

```
- index.js
- public
    - index.html
```

Your `index.js`:

```
"use strict";
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let router = express.Router();

// custom urls (defined by me)
app.get("/foo", function(req,res) {
    res.send('yay')
});

// static files
app.use("/", express.static("public"));

// error pages (404, 500):
router.use((req, res, next) => { res.send("Custom 404 page."); });
router.use((err, req, res, next) => { res.send("Custom 500 page."); });

app.use(router); // put it here instead of the beginning

app.listen(6666);
```

Output of `/foo`:

```
$ http get localhost:6666/foo
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 09:54:30 GMT
ETag: W/"3-QCrLHD4/N9puG7bKytwxXQ"
X-Powered-By: Express

yay
```

Output of `/`:

```
$ http get localhost:6666
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 129
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 09:51:15 GMT
ETag: W/"81-15383fa840c"
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 09:49:06 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Yay!!!
</body>
</html>
```

Output of `/bar`:

```
$ http get localhost:6666/bar
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 09:51:19 GMT
ETag: W/"10-cReU2J3jD/VaD5KVhqwLow"
X-Powered-By: Express

Custom 404 page.
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, interesting. Works here and in a minimal example I set up but now in my app... Debugging.

Comment: Ah, instead of `app.use` I was doing `myRouter.use(/* handle errors */)`. Maybe you have a good answer to [this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36028570/1420197).

Comment: Just did. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated my answer. Put ```app.use(router)``` to the end.